# How to pass parameters to Contract constructor using when using assembly?

Tags: contract-deployment, assembly

Here I have a function which deploys a Contract straight from bytecode, but let say my contract needs some arguments in the constructor, is it possible to pass them through `create opcode`?

```
function deployCode(bytes _code) returns (address deployedAddress) {
    assembly {
        deployedAddress := create(0, add(_code, 0x20), mload(_code))
        jumpi(invalidJumpLabel, iszero(extcodesize(deployedAddress)))
    }
    return deployedAddress
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructor arguments are appended to the deployment byte code in the [standard ABI format](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI).

For example, this contract takes `uint` constructor argument.

```
contract Foo {
    uint a;
    function Foo(uint _a) public {
        a = _a;
    }
}
```

It compiles to the following deployment bytecode:

```
0x60606040523415600e57600080fd5b6040516020806073833981016040528080519060200190919050508060008190555050603580603e6000396000f3006060604052600080fd00a165627a7a72305820f8da2d5811af956ad9465b607d0bce8b63b85210cd2c6faf9af78ce7b2eb3d6f0029
```

If we want to pass the value 42 (0x2a) to the constructor then we append the 32-byte ABI version of 0x2a to the bytecode that we give to the `CREATE` operation. The constructor knows where to find it.  I.e. Pass this to `CREATE`:

```
0x60606040523415600e57600080fd5b6040516020806073833981016040528080519060200190919050508060008190555050603580603e6000396000f3006060604052600080fd00a165627a7a72305820f8da2d5811af956ad9465b607d0bce8b63b85210cd2c6faf9af78ce7b2eb3d6f0029000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a
```

When the contract is `CREATE`d, its storage will be immediately populated with 42.

This is exactly the same as passing constructor parameters when creating a contract from an Externally Owned Account.

Comment: You made my day!